# What are the settings that SQLite is compiled with for PHP 5?

Tags: php, database, configuration, sqlite, pdo

SQLite 3.7 comes with the new [write-ahead logging (WAL)](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) and there are lots of settings that can [be configured](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html). However, there doesn't seem to be any way to change anything with the [PHP PDO SQlite lib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php). The sqlite3.ini file included with the PHP extension only has one configuration option.

Is there somewhere I can see which options the PHP project compiles SQLite with? Is there a way to build my own sqlite extension for PHP so I can configure these settings?

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`phpinfo()`**](https://www.php.net/phpinfo), you should be able to see which version of the SQLite library PHP has been compiled against.

For instance, here's what I have on my PHP 5.3.2 install *(the default version of some not too-recent Ubuntu)* :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5625435-2.png))</sub>

And, for PDO :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5625435-1.png))</sub>

I suppose you could have something more recent by recompiling PHP from source -- and, probably, using a more recent version of the SQLite development library.

For example, here's a screenshot of the relevant section of `phpinfo()`'s output from a PHP 5.3.99 build I did this week-end *(on Ubuntu 10.10)* :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5625435-3.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will help someone new to SQLite that needs to know which version they are running so they can choose the correct compile options.