# How do you enable Write-ahead log for SQLite3 in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

It is supposed to help with concurrency by writing to a temporary file.

However, when I try to do multiple writes at the same time I am met with a "database is locked" error. It does not create a temporary file and write later on.

How can I enable write-ahead log?

Or is it already enabled by default?

I am using PHP 7 with NGINX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625435/what-are-the-settings-that-sqlite-is-compiled-with-for-php-5

Comment: @miken32 What's the relevance? That's for PHP5 and was asked 10 years ago...

Comment: PHP version is irrelevant. It will still give you info on the compiled-in version of SQLite that may be helpful.

Comment: @miken32 That answer literally just says "Check PHP Info", which I have done and it does not say anything regarding write-ahead log.

Comment: Only one connection can write to a sqlite database at a time. WAL just allows other connections to read at the same time as one is writing. See https://sqlite.org/wal.html for details, including how to turn it on.